# Google Tag Manager for .Net Maui

Tags: .net, maui, google-tag-manager

I have a .Net MAUI project and I need to add Google Tag Manager to the project. The project targets net7.0-android and net7.0-ios. I cannot figure out how to do this. There seems to be no proper documentation on how to do this.

Comment: We (the Google Cloud client libraries team for .NET) don't support MAUI, Blazor, Unity etc I'm afraid. (That doesn't mean the libraries definitely don't work on those platforms - it means we don't test there, and don't provide support for trying to *get* them to work.) The main challenges are authentication and (for relevant libraries) gRPC support.